# meteorite error Cloning Mac

Tags: macos, git, meteorite

This is the error I keep getting when I try to run meteorite

`$ mrt`

Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
✓ router
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.5.3

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:108
        throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url;
                                                   ^
There was a problem cloning repo: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git

I've tried `sudo -H npm install -g meteorite`
I've installed and reinstalled it a bunch of times
I have git installed, I have Xcode installed, I have Homebrew installed and I have meteor.
All of those work.

This is my `$PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

This is `which Git
/usr/local/bin/git`

This is `which mrt
/usr/local/bin/mrt`

Not sure if this is relevant but I have two drives in my Mac one that has the user folder and the other that has system files.

Any help? I'm a unix newb so please be very clear on solutions. Thanks

Comment: for future reference: use backticks "`" or four leading spaces (available from the toolbar) to format code and make the post easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Error, make sure the Volume name has no SPACES. Mine had a few spaces and Meteorite git.js doesn't account for that. Just rename the Volume with no SPACES and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try running it as root:

`$ sudo mrt`

I always have to do this when using Meteorite to bundle on remote machines.

You might also need to create a symbolic link on mrt..

`$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/mrt /usr/bin/mrt`

Comment: @flean Updated the answer.. try that and let me know.

Comment: that didn't work. I Changed my $PATH earlier today to /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin . Does that help?

Answer (score -1):

It might be solved already, but I had the same error.
It turned out that Apple wanted me to agree on Terms, which I found out after running:

```
git --version
```

I had to run this as a administrator

```
sudo git --version
```

And agree upon the long list of Apple Terms. Afterwards my meteorite (and GIT for that matter) was running like a charm again.