# mrt unable to clone repo

Tags: meteor, atmosphere, meteorite

I'm trying to add packages using meteorite from atmosphere, but it seems unable to clone the repo. Here is my error.

```
    mrt add momentjs
✓ momentjs
    tag: https://github.com/crapthings/meteor-momentjs.git#v2.1.0

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:108
        throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url;
                                                   ^
There was a problem cloning repo: https://github.com/crapthings/meteor-momentjs.git
```

Any ideas as to what might have gone wrong? git is in my PATH, and so is meteorite.

EDIT: This is running on OS X Mountain Lion

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you installed meteorite:

```
sudo mrt add momentjs
```

The [WTF](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/wtf/app) guide says that you might need to install meteorite with administrator rights. With my installation I also need to run `mrt` commands with `sudo`.

Comment: yes, i've installed mrt with sudo. also tried running mrt with sudo as well, but received the same error.

Comment: found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953063/meteorite-error-cloning-mac

Answer (score 0):

You can fix those issues by cleaning up the root owned files in your meteorite installation (or better: uninstall meteorite, clean up and reinstall it):

```
sudo mrt uninstall
sudo mrt uninstall --system
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

Don't forget the `-H` for setting the HOME variable to the root homedir in the last line. Afterwards you can do `mrt add whatsoever` without `sudo` again. Works for me, found here: https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite